# How to add 2 DKIM records when they are both sendgrid. Klaviyo and Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, dkim

We use Sendgrid to send out emails directly from our website. the record is

```
s1._domainkey.xxx.com s1.domainkey.uxxxxx.wxxx.sendgrid.net.
s2._domainkey.xxx.com sx.domainkey.uxxxxx.wxxx.sendgrid.net.
```

We also use Klaviyo which also uses sendgrid. They want their records to be...

```
s1._domainkey.xxx.com s1.domainkey.u161779.wxxx.sendgrid.net
s2._domainkey.xxx.com s2.domainkey.u161779.wxxx.sendgrid.net
```

How do I add both records? Thank you for looking at this.

***UPDATED WITH ANSWER***

For the Klaviyo CNAME records

change CNAME send to CNAME send.k (any letter will work)

change CNAME s1._domainkey to s1._domainkey.k

change CNAME s2._domainkey to s2._domainkey.k

There is an unlimited combination of ways you could do the above. This was just the approach that I used.

Comment: Hey @Billy, have you been able to manage it? I've got the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes updating comment above.

Comment: @billy I have a similar problem but no record that starts with CNAME send. What were the original three records?

Comment: I just had a nice chat with SendGrid support and they suggested using a custom DKIM selector: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication#using-a-custom-dkim-selector